# Bootstrap static navbar covers section

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have seem similar questions about the navbar covering the content, but my problem is that sometimes is covers the content and sometimes it displays correctly depending on which section I am in.

The website : http://www.torhatch.co.uk/index-tor.html

The problem :

I have a Bootstrap static navbar which sometimes displays the sections correctly, and sometimes covers the top of the section.

When the website is first loaded and I click on any of the sections (eg About), the top of that section is covered (despite a body padding-top of 50px).  This also happens if I click on Home (my first section) and then click on another section from here.

When I am in already one of the other sections (eg About) and I click on any of the sections, they display correctly (ie no content is covered).

Ie The navbar only covers the content when the section is chosen from the first section.

Also, when I am in the first section (Home) and I click Home again, the navbar disappears.

I think its something to do with affix-top but I cant find what.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit your top div from:

   ```
   <div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top affix-top" id="nav">
   ```

to:

```
     <div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="nav">
```

2. Remove style:

   ```
   position: static;
   ```

from id nav (#nav). I dont think this id is required but keep it if you are using it in your js.

Comment: I think you are close, but I already have   <div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="nav"> in my html.   The affix-top is assigned to the code when the page first loads - but I dont know what by.  The html code doesnt refer to affix-top and I cant find it in the bootstrap css.  affix-top is no where in my code!

Comment: yes you have..i am asking to replace it with <div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="nav">

Comment: I have replaced my original code : <div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" id="nav"> with your suggestion : <div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="nav"> but it doesnt help?

Comment: Do you know how the affix-top is getting assigned?

Comment: You have replaced div code but 'position: static;' style is still sitting at id nav(style.css:127). Remove that too. It is working with me..using chrome browser.

Comment: I cant see where the position:statis style is getting assigned.  It isnt in my html. <div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="nav">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

Comment: <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-justified">
       <li><a href="#section1">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section4">Reviews</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section5">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container -->
</div><!--/.navbar -->

<div class="divider" id="section1"></div>

Comment: FIXED : I didnt have style position: static so I couldnt remove it; but I have added #nav.affix-top {position: fixed;} and that has solved it.  Thanks